# Running vba code on PowerPoint presentation close

Tags: excel, vba, memory-leaks, powerpoint

I have a presentation that pulls data from an Excel spreadsheet. I'm using this create a new instance of Excel:

```
 Public Sub InitExcel()
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set wbWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(ActivePresentation.Path & "\Data.xlsx", ReadOnly:="True", Notify:="false")
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set wsTechnologies = wbWorkbook.Worksheets("Technologies")
End Sub
```

Then once I've retrieved the data, I close Excel with

```
xlApp.Quit
xlApp = Nothing
```

Unfortunately this makes two problems. One is that it doesn't always close Excel and I always seem to be left with at least one instance in the Task Manager. The other one is that I want to display different data every time the user clicks on a different shape, so the way I'm doing it at the moment, every time a click happens Excel has to initialise, get the data, and quit... pretty slow.

So is there a better way to interface with Excel? Can I initialise it once, leave it open, and tell it to quit once the user exits the presentation? Or is there another way?

**Update:**
I have discovered that [there is a way to trigger events on close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211599(v=office.11).aspx). Still left with a loose Excel instance after calling

```
xlApp.quit
```

and

```
set xlApp = nothing
```

though. It closes when PowerPoint is though, so maybe it's not such an issue.